FIDE Ratings Updating after Month of finishing
I saw a similar question but still didn't get it.
If a tournament was finished 2 month ago, but only submitted and rated now and in the meantime I've played another event which hasn't been submitted yet. Will my rating be calculated taking into account the rating change from the previous tournament or calculated as registered for the last one event?


Will my rating be calculated taking into account the rating change from the previous tournament or calculated as registered for the last one event?

Your new rating will be calculated using the ratings in the latest rating list for you and your opponents. Any tournament you played in the interim which has not been submitted and rated cannot be taken into account.
Let me give you an example which might make it clearer.
In the May rating list your rating is 1500. In May you play a tournament, A, which is not submitted by your federation until July. In June you play another tournament, B, which is submitted also in July. You play in another tournament, C, which is not submitted until August.
What rating will they use for you when they calcultate your rating changes for the different tournaments?
Both tournaments A and B were submitted in July. They will both be rated in August and your rating in the latest list is still 1500 so that rating will be used for both tournaments. The fact that one was played before the other is irrelevant.
Suppose you played well in A and B and your rating went up to 1600. Since that is your current rating when tournament C is rated that is the rating they will use for you in calculating your new rating.

I still don't seem to get this. Mind if you could explain if i give an example?
Report for September 2022, Report for October 2022. Note that both have used the same Ro and K values

@cmgchess "Note that both have used the same Ro and K values" That is correct and what I said. All calculations in a particular month will use the same Ro. Any newly calculated value will only be used in the following month. The same for K value which has been scaled down this month because of the large number of games played
